# Dynamic attribute assignment without attributeCollection support?

Tags: railo, cfml

I notice that even in Railo 4.2 the cfloop tag does not support attributeCollection. What then is the best way to implement dynamic attribute assignment? The code I want to make dynamic is:

```
<cfscript>
query_opts = {
    query="fw.report.data",
}
if (IsSet(fw.report,'group')) query_opts.group="#fw.report.group#";
</cfscript>

<cfloop attributeCollection="#query_opts#">

    <!--- Does not group --->

</cfloop>

<cfloop query="#query_opts.query#" group="#query_opts.group#">

    <!--- Grouping works --->

    <cfif IsSet(query_opts,'group')>
        <cfoutput><h2>#fw.report.data[query_opts.group]#</h2></cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

The second version works and group can be allocated the empty string but how can I remove the attribute entirely if needed (eg, because group="" is invalid)? How do I make group optional in the code above without repeating the entire loop structure in an if/else conditional?

EDIT: I'm looking for a general-purpose solution rather than one specific to the cfloop / group attribute.

Comment: one way to get around it could be grouping by an empty value in your query, i.e. `select '' as nogroupby` and passing in a dynamic value to the `group=""` statement.

Comment: thanks matt, I'd rather a more general purpose solution (as in works for other tags/attributes) since I already have a workaround. I guess the code above should be considered an example of the issue rather than the issue itself.

Comment: how about rolling your own custom cfloop tag that wraps the coldfusion built in cfloop tag that way you can implement attributes collection? if that sounds interesting i could whip something up.

Comment: @M.Scherzer That would still require passing dynamic attributes to cfloop which is exactly the issue I want to solve in the first place. I'm starting to think it can't be done because CFLOOP affects the compiler and not just the runtime.

Comment: but then you have a general purpose solution. ;) you could of course get your hands dirty and implement this functionality and commit it to RAILO source.